# How to make two states in mobx that toggle each other?

Tags: typescript, mobx

I'm trying to create an object that has two flags that can't be both true. How do I do that? I can't find a relevant example in the docs. I was thinking somewhere in the lines of:

```
class Store {
  private _flag1: boolean = false;
  private _flag2: boolean = false;
  get flag1() { return this._flag1; }
  set flag1(v: boolean) { this._flag1 = v; if (v) this._flag2 = !v }
  get flag2() { return this._flag2; }
  set flag2(v: boolean) { this._flag2 = v; if (v) this._flag1 = !v }

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, { /* what do I write here??? */ }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark underlying flags as `observable`s, and getters as `computed`s, setters will be marked as `action`s automatically:

```
  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      _flag1: observable,
      _flag2: observable,
      flag1: computed,
      flag2: computed,
    }
  }
```

Or you could you use `makeAutoObservable` to do this automatically.

[Relevant section from the docs](https://mobx.js.org/computeds.html#computed-setter)

Comment: Why declare private members observable? A flag will only be changed via the setter, which is already defined as action. I guess I'm missing the logic behind this...

Comment: That's how MobX works, every value should be observable, otherwise observers won't be notified and your computeds won't rerun. Just read this part of the docs about the basics https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html